# Netbeans 7.3.1 or higher with Glassfish 4 shows IOException Warning but have no issue with Netbeans 7.2.1 with Glassfish 3.2

Tags: java, jsf, netbeans, primefaces, glassfish

I am having trouble figuring out why same project works perfectly with Netbeans 7.2.1 with Glassfis 3.2 and thows IOException warning while running on Netbeans 7.3.1 or higher (ie 7.4) with glassfish 4. I always get this particular kind of warning that I cannot shake it off from my console:

```
 WARNING:   JSF1064: Unable to find or serve resource, theme.css, from library, primefaces-redmond.
WARNING:   java.io.IOException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write(SocketDispatcher.java:51)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:93)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:51)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:487)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.flushByteBuffer(TCPNIOTransport.java:1252)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOAsyncQueueWriter.write0(TCPNIOAsyncQueueWriter.java:107)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.AbstractNIOAsyncQueueWriter.write(AbstractNIOAsyncQueueWriter.java:296)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.AbstractNIOAsyncQueueWriter.write(AbstractNIOAsyncQueueWriter.java:203)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.AbstractNIOAsyncQueueWriter.write(AbstractNIOAsyncQueueWriter.java:73)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransportFilter.handleWrite(TCPNIOTransportFilter.java:128)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.TransportFilter.handleWrite(TransportFilter.java:191)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$8.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:111)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.FilterChainContext.write(FilterChainContext.java:853)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.FilterChainContext.write(FilterChainContext.java:822)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.io.OutputBuffer.flushBuffer(OutputBuffer.java:1011)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.io.OutputBuffer.write(OutputBuffer.java:676)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.writeBytes(OutputBuffer.java:355)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.write(OutputBuffer.java:342)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteOutputStream.write(CoyoteOutputStream.java:161)
    at java.nio.channels.Channels$WritableByteChannelImpl.write(Channels.java:458)
    at com.sun.faces.application.resource.ResourceHandlerImpl.handleResourceRequest(ResourceHandlerImpl.java:343)
    at javax.faces.application.ResourceHandlerWrapper.handleResourceRequest(ResourceHandlerWrapper.java:153)
    at org.primefaces.application.PrimeResourceHandler.handleResourceRequest(PrimeResourceHandler.java:99)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:643)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:344)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at com.hilltop.RequestFilter.doFilter(RequestFilter.java:44)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:316)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:260)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:188)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:191)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:168)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:189)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

I am not getting what is going on. I tried to supress warnings but it didn't work. There is no issue when I use Netbeans 7.2.1 with Glassfish 3.2. "chain.doFilter(req, res);" is the one line that is throwing the above IOException. I tried to throw the issue, tried to catch with multiple catch statement and other possible combination with res,req or request response but nothing works. Following is the code:

```
 public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) {
        try {
            HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
            HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
            HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
            System.out.println(request.getRequestURI());
            if (session == null || session.getAttribute("online") == null) {
                response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"); // HTTP 1.1.
                response.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache"); // HTTP 1.0.
                response.setDateHeader("Expires", 0); // Proxies.
                chain.doFilter(req, res);//this is the line that gives the above issues
            } else {
                chain.doFilter(req, res);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Some IO Related exception");
        }
    }
```

So please if any of you know what is going on with this, let me know. I am still a beginner and wanna learn java JSF.

Thanks

Comment: I am also getting the same issue.